# How to echo just one message for a php foreach loop result and hide the message if there are no results?

Tags: php, postgresql

Hi I am trying to display a common message for the results of a php foreach loop. The message has to be displayed before the results, and should not be displayed if there are no results.

```
<!-- An array coming from the previous page -->
$string = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($_SESSION['grid']));

<!-- HIDE THIS MESSAGE IF THERE ARE NO RESULTS --> 
<label>These barcodes don't exist:</label>   

foreach ($string as $value) {
    <!-- SQL QUERY -->
    $query1 = "select addl_item_code_barcode from items where 
    addl_item_code_barcode = '$value';";
    $result = pg_query($db, $query1);

    <!-- IF THE VALUES IN THE ARRAY DON'T EXIST IN THE DATABASE THEN IT IS TO 
    BE DISPLAYED -->
    if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo $value; echo' ';
    } 
}
```

The problem is that multiple values won't be displayed outside the loop, and the results won't be displayed before the loop. How do I solve this?

Comment: You need to explain a little bit more. Your requirements are not cleared

Comment: I'm not sure to understand well... use an `if` statement?

Comment: I want the results of the foreach loop i.e $value to be displayed with the message in the label above the foreach loop. And hide the message in the label if there are no results.

Comment: you have to execute the foreach loop before your label

Comment: Okay then how to hide the label if the foreach doesn't return any results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$nonexistent = array();
foreach ($string as $value) {

$query1 = "select addl_item_code_barcode from items where 
addl_item_code_barcode = '$value';";
$result = pg_query($db, $query1);


if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
array_push($nonexistent,$value);
        } 
}
if(count($nonexistent)>0){
    echo "<label>These barcodes don't exist:</label> <br/>";
    foreach($nonexistent as $element){
        echo $element . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't echo your output immediately, but store it in a string variable and then output it after your label

```
<?php
// An array coming from the previous page
$string = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($_SESSION['grid']));
$values = "";

foreach ($string as $value) {
    <!-- SQL QUERY -->
    $query1 = "
        SELECT addl_item_code_barcode 
          FROM items 
         WHERE addl_item_code_barcode = '$value'
             ;
    ";
    $result = pg_query($db, $query1);

    // IF THE VALUES IN THE ARRAY DON'T EXIST IN THE DATABASE THEN IT IS TO BE DISPLAYED
    if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        $values .= "{$value} ";
    } 
}

if (strlen($values) === 0) {
    // HIDE THIS MESSAGE IF THERE ARE NO RESULTS
    ?><label>These barcodes don't exist:</label><?php
}
```